# How do you call a function with an array of structs?

Tags: c

I have the following LCD driver code, and I am unsure how to call this function

```
typedef struct  {
  int16_t X;
  int16_t Y;
} Point, * pPoint;

void LCD_PolyLine(pPoint Points, uint16_t PointCount) {
  int16_t X = 0, Y = 0;
  while(--PointCount) {
    X = Points->X;
    Y = Points->Y;
    Points++;
    LCD_DrawUniLine(X, Y, Points->X, Points->Y);
  }
}
```

It doesn't make sense to have the first argument of the function be "pPoint Points". To me it seems like it should be "pPoint *Points". I could then create an array of pPoints and pass this address to it.

How else would you call this driver function without modifying it?

Comment: `pPoint` to a pointer to `Point` in this case (well, technically a pointer to `struct {...}`), so you should create an array of `Point`s.

Comment: It's generally a bad idea to typedef a pointer, as demonstrated by this question. I would delete the `, * pPoint` at the end of the typedef, and declare the function as `void LCD_PolyLine(Point *Points,...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> It doesn't make sense to have the first argument of the function be `pPoint Points`.

It actually makes perfect sense, because `pPoint` is defined as `Point*`, i.e. a pointer to `Point`. It is equivalent to

```
void LCD_PolyLine(Point *Points, uint16_t PointCount)
```

which is the correct signature. All you need to do is to pass an array of `struct Point`, followed by the count of elements in it.

Comment: Ah I see now! I was creating an array of pPoint (i.e. Point **) which is why I had the confusion. When I just create an array of Point it works out perfectly. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

On the last line of the the `Point` struct and typedef definition, after the comma it says `* pPoint`. This is notation that defines the type `pPoint` as a `Point *`. Note the "p" on `pPoint` is common notation for a pointer type. So you are right, you can just normally create an array of `Point` structs and pass the pointer to the function. (Just be careful not to pass the address of the pointer, which would be a `Point **`.)